# write a java file from a string (The string content from a text file by reading it line by line)

Tags: java

I want to save the content of the string to a Java file.
The content of the string "sttr" is read from a text file line by line.
When I run the code I got correct output but when I try to write the content to a Java file I got only one line. Code:

```
String content = " test ";   
String content1 = "test01";
//read text file line by line

try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("E:\\test\\myfile.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String strLine;
    String sttr ;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        sttr = strLine;
        System.out.println(content+sttr+content1);

        File file = new File("E:/test/output.java");
        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        //bw.write(content);
        bw.write(content+sttr+content1);
        //bw.write(content1);
        //bw.close();
        //System.out.println("Done");      
    }
}  
catch (Exception e) { //Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Indent your code, and you'll suddenly realize that you create and write your file **inside** the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't recreate your BufferedWriter at each time, do it once outside the loop. Otherwise, it will erase the content of the file.

```
File file = new File("E:/test/output.java");
// if file doesnt exists, then create it
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

String strLine;
String sttr ;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // [...]
```